Register android intent filter to only accept files
I have an app that you can share files to
I want it to show up whenever you share files.
I tried the following
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>

but the problem is the app shows up in the share menu when the user shares text or any other data that is not a file.

What you want does not really exist in Android.
The closest you will get is to add <data android:scheme="content"> and <data android:scheme="file"> to your <intent-filter>. The latter would give you what you want... except that the file scheme has largely been banned for nearly a decade. The content scheme is used for data streams like files, but it is also used for other things, and your app will show up in share menus for them as well. UPDATE: sorry, this too will only work for ACTION_VIEW.
If you were supporting ACTION_VIEW instead of ACTION_SEND, adding <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" /> to your <intent-filter> (along with the two <data> elements mentioned above) would restrict you to data streams, which would get you closer to what you want, though not via share menus.

App disappears from share menu when I just add <data android:scheme="content"/> to the code in the question.

@Ammar: Ack! Sorry, that too only will work for ACTION_VIEW. I have updated the answer accordingly.
